# Reference linked table filepath in VBA code Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want to reference the filepath of a linked table database in my database's VBA code because the link changes sometimes, so I can't just reference a static filepath.  It is linked to an Excel document, and ideally I would like to also grab the name of the sheet that is linked, if possible.  Is there a way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Exactly how is the link path changed? If this is done with code then the path should already be available.

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

`CurrentDb.TableDefs("TableNameHere").SourceTableName`

And

`CurrentDb.TableDefs("TableNameHere").Connect`

Connect property will return the entire connection string like:
**Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=2;ACCDB=YES;DATABASE=C:\Users\June\Condos.xlsx**

Use string manipulation functions to extract path part, like;

`Mid(x, InStrRev(x, "=") + 1)`